# How to calculate $E[\sup_{s\in[t,t+a]}(B_s-s)]$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

At first, I was trying to calculate the $E[\sup_{s\in[t,t+a]}(B_s-s)^+]$, here "a" is a constant. since $Y:=\sup_{s\in[t,t+a]}(B_s-s)^+$ is a positive r.v, so $E[\sup_{s\in[t,t+a]}(B_s-s)^+]=\int_0^{\infty}P(Y>\lambda)d\lambda$, and $\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}P(Y>\lambda)=0, \forall t $, so it has a chance to converge, then I use martingale inequality to estimate $P(Y>\lambda)$, but it doesn't work. My final goal is to have $E[\sup_{s\in[t,t+a]}(B_s-s)]<C$ holds for a constant which does not depend on t. Any ideas or references on calculating  $E[\sup_{s\in[t,t+a]}(B_s-s)]$ will be of great help.

Comment: Intuitively, I feel like you should apply towering property. That's how most of these problems are solved. I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: Since $B_s-s\to-\infty$ almost surely when $s\to\infty$, the finiteness of $\sup\limits_tE(Y_t)$ is rather clear. Actually, $E(Y_t)=E((B_t-t+Z)^+)$ where $Z$ is distributed like $Y_0$ and independent of $B_t$ hence one can even expect that $E(Y_t)$ might be a decreasing function of $t$.